# Why is "prima" not inflected?

Tags: adjective

Reasons for non-inflection of adjectives are

1. Fixed expressions (ruhig Blut)
2. Color words (lila Haus)
3. derivations with -er (Hamburger Marktplatz)

But "prima" does not seem to fit into any of those categories.

Comment: It might disappoint you but the reason is because it isn't. It's probably a result of the etymology: https://www.dwds.de/wb/prima#etymwb-1

Comment: @Roland - It's from the feminine form of the Italian "primo", but I guess the Italian inflection was lost in the process. But I've never noticed that the fact that a word is imported stopped German speakers from adding their own endings, for example "Du babysittest ihn." But you're right that sometimes things just are with no particular reason. Perhaps in this case German declension would be too awkward; "ein prima-es Mädchen" doesn't really work.

Comment: @RDBury An adjective without declination works well in German grammar because cases can be expressed by an article. A verb without conjugation is a very different kind of beast. Conjugation of "babysitten" would be avoided by most Germans. It feels akward. duden.de points out that the infinitive is mostly used.

Answer (score 1):

The rule, that color words are not inflected is wrong. Here are counter examples:

- **rot:** der rote Autobus, ein roter Luftballon. Ich sehe den roten Mantel.
- **grün:** der grüne Autobus, ein grüner Luftballon. Ich sehe den grünen Mantel.
- **blau:** der blaue Autobus, ein blauer Luftballon. Ich sehe den blauen Mantel.
- **gelb:** der gelbe Autobus, ein gelber Luftballon. Ich sehe den gelben Mantel.
- **braun, türkis, schwarz, weis, ...** They all are inflected, just like all other adjectives.

The reason, why *»lila«* and *»rosa«* are not inflected when they are used as attributes of nouns is a different reason:

##### Adjectives, that end with the letter *»a«* are not inflected.

Adjectives ending with *»a«* are very rare in German language. None of them is inflected:

- **rosa:** der rosa Autobus, ein rosa Luftballon. Ich sehe den rosa Mantel.
- **lila:** der lila Autobus, ein lila Luftballon. Ich sehe den lila Mantel.
- **extra:** eine extra Gebühr verlangen; bitte mit extra Pommes
- **prima:** eine prima Idee; prima Arbeit leisten

In colloquial speech I found two more. They are adjectives that in good-style standard German are only used predicative, i.e. not as attribute of a noun:

- **mega:** Das Konzert war mega = Es war ein mega Konzert.
- **gaga:** Meine Tante ist komplett gaga. → Meine gaga Tante kommt zu Besuch.

Comment: Many native speakers prefer not to inflect *türkis*. Also, of course color adjectives can be compared; see for instance https://www.dwds.de/wb/rot.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Are you referring to using another word instead, "türkisfarben"? It is true that is sometimes used; personally, I perceive both "das türkise Auto" and "das türkisfarbene Auto" to sound idiomatic.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper *Türkis* is different from *Braun, schwarz, weiß*; a fact that the answer could address.

Comment: @DavidVogt: The question was not about türkis and not mainly about color adjectives. If türkis really was different, I would delete it from my answer. But I can't see any difference to rot, grün and blau: [Das türkise Geilomobil](https://www.profil.at/morgenpost/das-tuerkise-geilomobil-in-einzelteilen/402575603) - [die türkise Seilschaft](https://kontrast.at/wer-folgt-kurz/) - [Was bleibt von der türkisen ÖVP?](https://www.diepresse.com/6204342/mitreden-bei-der-causa-schmid-was-bleibt-von-der-tuerkisen-oevp) - I never heard or read »türkisfarben« or an uninflected usage of türkis.

Comment: Why search for examples with inflected *türkis* but not for *türkisfarben*? Wouldn't it be more useful to search for examples of the word you don't know?

Answer (score 0):

Very likely the main reason is: Inflection would simply sound awkward to German speakers.

- <s>ein rosaer Wagen</s>
- <s>ein superer Gewinn</s>
- <s>eine spitzere</s> (*from "spitze", not "spitz"*) Note
- <s>ein schnuppes Argument</s> (*from "schnuppe"*)
- <s>zweierleie Pralinen</s>

Non-inflectable adjectives often end with a vocal (like "rosa", "lila", "prima". Inflecting them makes them sound awkwardly stuttering.

(BTW: From my list of examples of indeclinable adjectives you can easily see that the three reasons you list in your question are by far not exhaustive)

Comment: "rosa" isn't the best example. ["Flektierte Formen wie rosane finden sich nur selten und gelten als umgangssprachlich."](https://www.dwds.de/wb/rosa) To me, "ein rosaner Wagen" sounds just fine.

Comment: Farbworte werden gebeugt, indem "-farben" angehängt wird: "Der Wagen ist rosa." -> "Der rosa*farbene* Wagen". I wonder if "schnuppe" is really an *Adjektiv*, I know it only in phrases like "Das ist *mir* schnuppe." (that would be an *Adverb*)

Comment: @bakunin All my dictionaries agree that "schnuppe" is an adjective.

Comment: @roland *ngrams* tells me "rosane" is really extremely rare. And no, to me it doesn't sound acceptable.

Comment: @bakunin Die meisten Farbworte werden einfach "ganz normal" gebeugt: "Das gelbe Auto". Nur *manche* Farbworte sind speziell und fordern einen Ersatz, der sich beugen läßt.

Comment: @tofro: *diese* Farbworte waren war eigentlich gemeint (nur nicht geschrieben)

Comment: @tofro Of course it is rare in google ngrams. It is Umgangssprache and might even be slightly regional. I grew up with "rosane" und "lilane" but I wouldn't use them in writing. My point is that there is already an existing mechanism which allows declination without the akwardness of having er/e/es/en follow a vowel.

Comment: On the other hand, I only have ever heard, read or used "schnuppe" and "spitze" in combination with "sein", such as "Das is' mir schnuppe." Using them in front of a noun is surely much less common than "rosane". "spitze" would go into a compound noun and not be used as an adjective in such cases.

Comment: @roland well, that seems to be more of a symptom than a reason.

Comment: @Roland: Adjectives can usually be used attributive (*laute Kinder*), predicative (*Kinder sind laut*) and adverbial (*Kinder schreien laut*). But there are some exceptions that can't be used attributive, but still are adjectives: *plemplem, kirre, gaga, weg, fort, futsch, pleite, quitt, schuld, ...* And *»schnuppe«* is one of them.

Comment: @Roland: Du hast das spitze beschrieben, aber ich kenne auch den adverbialen Gebrauch von "spitze"; außerdem fände ich es spitze, wenn auch Verben außer "sein" Erwähnung fänden. (Sorry for switching to German, but I couldn't resist integrating my examples in the text.)